# Mule 4.2.2 Not supporting take function in Dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mule-esb, mulesoft

I'm Using Mule latest runtime 4.2.2 as mentioned in this page below. I'm trying replicate `take` function example. Looks like till it is not supported in this version.

Do i need to take any special studio `updates` to make it work?

[Mule-4.2/dw-arrays-functions-take](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-arrays-functions-take)

studio error says : `unable to resolve reference of take`.

I would expect this should work in this version 4.2.2.
  Anyone facing similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out my own, just in case if anyone facing the same issue. If you are importing

`import * from dw::core::Arrays` in dataweave. Once after saving it try restarting the application. It works.